# How do I deny private variables from reading in python?

Tags: python, v8, pyv8

I am trying to execute javascript code in python, using `pyv8` safely. At the end of the day, I have an object being used by javascript, with few fields I would like to have hidden.

I know python doesn't have encapsulation [(as explained in this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138734/how-do-i-make-private-variables-inaccessable-in-python), but yet, is there a way to disable access using `__getattribute__`?

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self, debug):
        self._a = ...
        self._b = ...
        self._c = ...
        self._unlocked = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self._unlocked = True

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._unlocked = False

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if object.__getattribute__(self, "_unlocked"):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

        if name.startswith("_"):
            return None

        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

So this object denies access to a "private" variables, unless unlocked using like this:

```
ctx = Context()
...
with ctx:
   # _b is accessible here
   print ctx._b
```

As far as there's no way to do `with` from javascript, nor to call `__enter__` since the object is "locked".

Seems not very efficient though. Is there a better way?

Comment: Name mangling performed by two leading underscores will cover all valid use cases of 'private variables' in python.

Comment: Note that variables like `__foo` will be mangled so they're not easily visible to code outside the class that contains them (although you can get around it). the `__` is more of a "stay away even if you're not technically prevented from doing so".

Comment: Yes, '__a' is actually available as '_A__a' by compiler. What I want is to literally disable any way to get the value.

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing this in an attempt to sandbox the JS so you can run untrusted code...

Comment: @SeanMcSomething well, kinda. I want sandbox javascript code, not python. Is there a way to access object's attributes, if object denies so via `__getattribute__`? That's why I try to use `with`. Please explain why it's bad and why it won't work.

Comment: @desertkun - once the JS is able to call into your Python arbitrarily, you've already lost the game.  Python's a highly dynamic language & any sort of security restrictions like that should be enforced at the level of the JS interpreter itself - probably by giving it a whitelist of objects it's allowed to access and not putting any sensitive data inside of them.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething Could you please elaborate this https://github.com/buffer/pyv8/pull/2 ? If you familiar with `V8`, I've patched it so it returns `null` for every `python` object starting with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property getter that restricts access?

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
    """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return "Property can not be accessed."

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

More info can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: The thing is that this doesn't prevent a user from accessing `foo._x`.

Comment: If the user has a reference to `foo`, she can get to any of `foo`'s data.  This is why python no longer pretends to have a sandboxed execution mode.  What you're asking for isn't possible in Python.