# Python's accessible class variables, sensitive data, and malicious coders (black-hat hackers)

Tags: python, class, security, data-science, private

I was trying to make a variable inaccessible for a project I'm doing, and I ran across an SO post on [Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641219/6505499). For me, it raised some interesting questions that, to try and make this answerable, I'll label with <sup>Q1</sup> , <sup>Q2</sup> , etc. I've looked around, but I didn't find answers to the questions I'm asking, especially to those about sensitive data.

I found useful stuff in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641219/6505499), but it seems that the general consensus was something like *if you see a variable with a `_` before it, act like an adult and realize you shouldn't be messing with it*. The same kind of idea was put forward for variables preceded by `__`. There, I got the general idea that you trust people not to use tricks like those described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#comment41361223_25614597) and (in more detail) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32802486/6505499). I also found some good information at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28138734/6505499).

This is all very good advice when you're talking about good coding practices.

I posted some thoughts in comments to the posts I've shared. My main question [was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#comment101593673_1641236) as a comment.

> I'm surprised there hasn't been more discussion of those who want to introduce malicious code. This is a real question: **Is there no way in Python to prevent a black-hat hacker from accessing your variables and methods and inserting code/data that could deny service, reveal personal (or proprietary company) information<sup>Q1</sup>**? **If Python doesn't allow this type of security, should it ever be used for sensitive data<sup>Q2</sup>**?

Am I totally missing something: **Could a malicious coder even access variables and methods to insert code/data that could deny service or reveal sensitive data<sup>Q3</sup>**?

I imagine I could be misunderstanding a concept, missing something, putting a problem in a place where it doesn't belong, or just being completely ignorant on what computer security is. However, I want to understand what's going on here. If I'm totally off the mark, I want an answer that tells me so, but I would also like to know how I'm totally off the mark and how to get back on it.

Another part of the question I'm asking here is from another comment I made on those posts/answers. @SLott [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641305/6505499) (somewhat paraphrased)

> ... I've found that `private` and `protected` are very, very important design concepts. But as a practical matter, in tens of thousands of lines of Java and Python, I've never *actually* used `private` or `protected`. ... Here's my question "protected [or private] from whom?"

To try and find out whether my concerns are anything to be concerned about, I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#comment101594236_1641305) on that post. Here it is, edited.

> Q: "protected from whom?" A: "From malicious, black-hat hackers who would want to access variables and functions so as to be able to deny service, to access sensitive info, ..." It seems the `A._no_touch = 5` approach would cause such a malicious coder to laugh at my "please don't touch this". My `A.__get_SSN(self)` seems to be just wishful hoping that B.H. (Black Hat) doesn't know the `x = A(); x._A__get_SSN()` trick ([trick by @Zorf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#comment41361223_25614597)).

I could be putting the problem in the wrong place, and if so, I'd like someone to tell me I'm putting the problem in the wrong place, but also to explain. **Are there ways of being secure with a class-based approach<sup>Q4</sup>**? **What other non-class-and-variable solutions are there for handling sensitive data in Python<sup>Q5</sup>**?

Here's some code that shows why I see the answers to these questions as a reason for wondering **if Python should ever be used for sensitive data <sup>Q2</sup>**. It's not complete code (why would I put these private values and methods down without using them anywhere?), but I hope it shows the type of thing I'm trying to ask about. I typed and ran all this at the Python interactive console.

```py
## Type this into the interpreter to define the class.
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Nice guy."
    self.just_a_4 = 4
    self.my_number = 4
    self._this_needs_to_be_pi = 3.14
    self.__SSN = "I hope you do not hack this..."
    self.__bank_acct_num = 123
  def get_info():
    print("Name, SSN, bank account.")
  def change_my_number(self, another_num):
    self.my_number = another_num
  def _get_more_info(self):
    print("Address, health problems.")
  def send_private_info(self):
    print(self.name, self.__SSN, self.__bank_acct_num)
  def __give_20_bucks_to(self, ssn):
    self.__SSN += " has $20"
  def say_my_name(self):
    print("my name")
  def say_my_real_name(self):
    print(self.name)
  def __say_my_bank(self):
    print(str(self.__bank_acct_num))
```

```py
>>> my_a = A()
>>> my_a._this_needs_to_be_pi
3.14
>>> my_a._this_needs_to_be_pi=4 # I just ignored begins-with-`_` 'rule'.
>>> my_a._this_needs_to_be_pi
4

## This next method could actually be setting up some kind of secure connection,  
## I guess, which could send the private data. I just print it, here.
>>> my_a.send_private_info()
Nice guy. I hope you do not hack this... 123

## Easy access and change a "private" variable
>>> my_a.__SSN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__SSN'
>>> my_a.__dict__
{'name': 'Nice guy.', 'just_a_4': 4, 'my_number': 4, '_this_needs_to_be_pi': 4, 
'_A__SSN': 'I hope you do not hack this...', '_A__bank_acct_num': 123}
>>> my_a._A__SSN
'I hope you do not hack this...'

# (maybe) potentially more dangerous
>>> def give_me_your_money(self, bank_num):
      print("I don't know how to inject code, but I can")
      print("access your bank account number:")
      print(my_a._A__bank_acct_num)
      print("and use my bank account number:")
      print(bank_num)
>>> give_me_your_money(my_a,345)
I don't know how to inject code, but I can
access your bank account number:
123
and use my account number:
345
```

At this point, I re-entered in the class definition, which probably wasn't necessary.

```py
>>> this_a = A()
>>> this_a.__give_20_bucks_to('unnecessary param')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__give_20_bucks_to'
>>> this_a._A__give_20_bucks_to('unnecessary param')
>>> this_a._A__SSN
'I hope you do not hack this... has $20'

## Adding a fake "private" variable, `this_a.__SSN`
>>> this_a.__SSN = "B.H.'s SSN"
>>> this_a.__dict__
{'name': 'Nice guy.', 'just_a_4': 4, 'my_number': 4, '_this_needs_to_be_pi': 3.14, 
'_A__SSN': 'I hope you do not hack this... has $20', '_A__bank_acct_num': 123, 
'__SSN': "B.H.'s SSN"}
>>> this_a.__SSN
"B.H.'s SSN"

## Now, changing the real one and "sending/stealing the money"
>>> this_a._A__SSN = "B.H.'s SSN"
>>> this_a._A__give_20_bucks_to('unnecessary param')
>>> this_a._A__SSN
"B.H.'s SSN has $20"
```

I've actually done some work at a previous contracting job with sensitive data - not SSNs and bank account numbers, but things like people's ages, addresses, phone numbers, personal history, marital and other relationship history, criminal records, etc. I wasn't involved in the programming to secure this data; I helped with trying to extract useful information by helping to ground-truth the data as preparation for machine learning. We had permission and legal go-aheads to work with such data. Another main question is this: **How, in Python, could one collect, manage, analyze, and draw useful conclusions with this sensitive data<sup>Q6</sup>**? From what I've discussed here, it doesn't seem that classes (or any of the other data structures, which I didn't go into here, but which seem to have the same problems) would allow this to be done securely (privately or in a protected manner. I imagine that a class-based solution probably has something to do with compilation. **Is this true<sup>Q7</sup>**?

Finally, since it wasn't security, but code reliability that brought me here, I'll post another post I found and comment I made to complete my questions.

@Marcin [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28138772/6505499),

> [In response to the OP's words,] "The problem is simple. I want private variables to be accessed and changed only inside the class." [Marcin responded] So, don't write code outside the class that accesses variables starting with `__`. Use `pylint` or the like to catch style mistakes like that.

My goal with [my following reply comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138734/how-do-i-make-private-variables-inaccessable-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment101594321_28138772) was to see if my thoughts represent actual coding concerns. I hope it did't come across as rude

> It seems this answer would be nice if you wrote code only for your own personal enjoyment and never had to hand it on to someone else to maintain it. Any time you're in a collaborative coding environment (any post-secondary education and/or work experience), the code will be used by many. Someone down the line will want to use an easy way to change your `__you_really_should_not_touch_this` variable. They may have a good reason for doing so, but it's possible you set up your code such that their "easy way" is going to break things.

**Is mine a valid point, or do most coders respect the double underscore<sup>Q8</sup>**? **Is there a better way, using Python, to protect the integrity of the code - better than the `__` strategy<sup>Q9</sup>**?

Comment: To protect the integrity of the code don't let everyone change it on your production machine.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, I agree that you shouldn't just let anyone change your code. However, I don't want my career to be about whatever code I'm working on now - I hope that at some point someone else will maintain it. It's for those types of situations that I ask the questions.

Comment: You are mixing up several levels of security. Once someone can touch your code, you are insecure whether or not your language enforces private attributes. If someone you don't trust maintains your code, you can't trust your code any more, whatever your programming language does. Private access is only here to protect from _other parts of your codebase_, mostly to enforce correct patterns. Unfortunately it includes libraries - the only attack vector that this leaves open. If you vet your libraries, this is not an issue. If you are using libraries whose integrity you don't trust, it's a problem.

Comment: I can only speak for me (and the companies I'm working for): If anyone changes the code he/she is a developer and has the right to that. What would I achieve with forced protection? If I can access the codebase I can just change private to public attributes.

Comment: Okay, I figured I was mixing up some things with security. You answer helps me understand that the `public`, `private`, `protected`, and underscores aren't about computer security. I had always thought they were. Your highlighted notes - underscoring protection from other parts of your code base - made the light bulb go off. Of course, I can run into all kinds of bugs if I haven't isolated each part of my code properly. Now what everyone was saying about `encapsulation` makes sense.

Comment: "Protected from whom" is indeed the correct question. You are already protected against a random black hat hacker who cannot access your machine due to physical security, firewalls, proper PAM setup, good passwords, any exposed services being coded against good security practices, and all that crud. If the black hat hacker accesses your machine, it's not because Python has no private variables, it's because someone at your company screwed up on physical or logical security, or they managed to hire someone malicious. And then not even Java or C++ with strong access checks will help you.

Comment: @Matthias, with your comments and those of Amadan, I'm realizing that I've been mixing up what parts of coding are security and what parts are ... how do I say ... code integrity.

Comment: That makes sense, @Amadan. I've never really learned computer security in any manner of detail, and these answers help. I do have a further question, though. I've heard that you need to protect against "code injection", which I understood to mean hijacking your code to insert malicious software. I'm trying to find a post that discusses something similar. If such protection isn't done with `private`, etc., how is it done?

Comment: You have to think _how_ code can be injected. The main ways are buffer overflows (on binary code that is not properly protected against it - not applicable to Python), the infamous `eval` function against unchecked user input, writing user input to unchecked user-specified file path, inserting unchecked user input into raw SQL queries. Not using `eval`, and being careful about user input is all you need. (`eval` has valid uses, but chances are you'll almost never run into one. Whenever tempted to use `eval` think if it can be done some other way, and almost certainly you'll find it can.)

Comment: Okay, @Amadan , I think I'm understanding this injection thing move. ... So with Python, the main concern with code injection would be things like `os.system('<some-bash-or-CMD-command>')` and the `subprocess` module. Right?

Comment: ...also not using libraries that you don't know if they are safe or not. E.g. everyone uses numpy, it would be a huge scandal if someone injected malicious code; smaller libraries might have malicious code, so if you have important data you need to know that they are safe, and the only way to do that is by reading it line by line (or trusting the maintainers). (Note that a malicious library could do _anything_ that the user executing the code is authorised for, so again it's not about privacy of variables.) E.g. [this](https://snyk.io/blog/malicious-code-found-in-npm-package-event-stream/)

Comment: No, having `os.system('<some-bash-or-CMD-command>')` in your code is just your code (e.g. `os.system('ls')` is a perfectly okay thing to have in your code) - or bad system security (where someone else changed your code). Code injection vulnerability is `os.system(something)`, where `something` is unchecked user input (e.g. a submit from a webpage).

Comment: Okay. Now I feel a lot better using those functions. They've always made me a bit nervous, but knowing I just need to make sure they are checked helps a lot. I've used such methods, but there's always been that "Is this safe?" question in the back of my mind. Now, I'll have a lot more confidence with them.

Comment: Consider this toy example: you have `.bz` files in `data` folder, and a web app route that takes a web submission `filename`, then returns the content of the `.bz` file to the client uncompressed: `filename = request.GET.get('filename', ''); return subprocess.check_output("bzcat data/" + filename + ".bz", shell=True)` Seems straightforward, right? If `filename` is `foo`, then you unbzip `data/foo.bz` and send it to user. What if it's `; rm -rf ~/* #`? The command that gets executed is `bzcat data/; rm -rf ~/* #.bz`, and all your data gets deleted. `rm` code successfully injected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`private` and `protected` do not exist for *security*. They exist to enforce *contracts* within your code, namely logical [*encapsulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). If you mark a piece as `protected` or `private`, it means that it is a ***logical*** implementation detail of the implementing class, and no other code should touch it directly, since other code may not [be able to] use it correctly and may mess up state.

E.g., if your logical rule is that whenever you change `self._a` you must also update `self._b` with a certain value, then you don't want external code to modify those variables, as your internal state may get messed up if the external code does not follow this rule. You want only your one class to handle this internally since that localises the potential points of failure.

In the end all this gets compiled into a big ball of bytes anyway, and all the data is stored in memory at runtime. At that point there is no protection of individual memory offsets within the application's scope anyway, it's all just byte soup. `protected` and `private` are constraints the programmer imposes on their own code to keep their own logic straight. For this purpose, more or less informal conventions like `_` are perfectly adequate.

An attacker cannot attack at the level of individual properties. The running software is a black box to them, whatever goes on internally doesn't matter. *If* an attacker is in a position to actually access individual memory offsets, or actually ***inject code***, then it's pretty much game over either way. `protected` and `private` doesn't matter at that point.

Comment: That perfectly covers all the things I've been learning from people's comments. I'm a physicist who learned to code for research, enjoyed it, and gone become a developer and researcher. This makes it so I run into these basic concepts that weren't part of my education. I'm not sure where I got the idea that `private`, `protected`, and underscores were part of computer security (maybe the word, protected,) but your answer very concisely fills in the gaps in my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: I think many a programmer has had the same misunderstanding; languages which do sport actual `protected` keywords also usually throw errors if you do try to access properties marked as such. This may enforce the notion that you "can't" access them. (Actually, you always can, you just have to be really deliberate about it.) In this sense I do like Python's approach; it doesn't even pretend that these attributes aren't accessible, it just wants you to be an adult about accessing them.